# How can i deploy a React JS app to Azure using commandline / Powershell?

Tags: reactjs, powershell

I have a react app that i deploy from Visual Studio , but how can i do it command line in Powershell ?
Currently i deploy my .net apps using Powershell as follows :

```
   & MSBuild.exe c:\mytest\test.csproj `
   /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 `
   /p:Configuration=Release `
   /p:Platform="AnyCPU" `
   /p:DeployOnBuild=true `
   /p:PublishProfile=$DeploymentPath `
   /p:Password=$password
```

Couldnt get it to work in comand line.
How can i do it in Powershell command line cli ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think its clear . do i need to call a file oin react js to compile on command line ?